# Mustache - Conditional on nested sections using same names

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a category nodes (an array of objects). I would like to print one list item if the `product` field exists, and a different list item if the `category` field exists.

```
category.nodes = [
  {
    product: "1",
    type: "product"
  },
  {
    product: "2",
    type: "product"
  },
  {
    category: "categoryName",
    type: "category"
  }      
]
```

My Mustache template is:

```
<p>
    {{#category.nodes}}
      {{#product}}
        <li>{{product}}</li>                            
      {{/product}}
      {{#category}}
        <li>{{category}}</li>
      {{/category}}
   {{/category.nodes}}
</p>
```

the `{{#category.nodes}} ... {{/category.nodes}}` should put the scope into the [category.nodes section](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#sections), and sections

> "render blocks of text one or more times, depending on the value of the key in the current context"

The documents state the following on [false values and empty lists](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#false-values-or-empty-lists):

> "If the person key does not exist, or exists and has a value of null, undefined, false, 0, or NaN, or is an empty string or an empty list, the block will not be rendered"

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj94ao0o/3/) demonstrates an issue when nested values are the same as parent values (`{{#category}}...{{/category}}` refers to the global `category`, not the category.nodes.category.)

I was wondering if there was some way to specify which `category` is being referenced, as this poses problems for nesting.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj94ao0o/4/) is a solution to the problem by changing the parent's name, I'm wondering if there is some way to specify which `category` is being referenced, as opposed to renaming variables.

The problem is the `{{#category}}...{{/category}}` printing when the section does not have a `category`.

Comment: Consider opening an issue on github since it seems like a bug

Comment: (for those following along) I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/629), I'll update when I have a response from the author =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior matches [the specification](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/specs/interpolation.yml).

> Walk the context stack from top to bottom, finding the first context
>   that is a) a hash containing the name as a key OR b) an object responding
>   to a method with the given name

When `{{#category}}` is not matched within the members of `category.nodes`, it walks the stack and finds `category` at the root (which is at the bottom of the stack in this terminology). From my reading of the specification, there is no way to discern the level of a data element.